# Nativescript Detect scroll event on ScrollView

Tags: scroll, scrollview, nativescript

is there a way to detect the scroll event for scrollView? I tried using

```
scroll.on('scroll', function(args){
  console.log('scroll')
 })
```

But its not working..

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event of the ScrollView will be exposed in the next version of {N} - 1.5. You can check out the [issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1057) in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

As of NativeScript 1.5 (Released November 24th, 2015) this can be detected just as you wrote the code in the initial post.